# MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Unsupported projection option: sort: { created_at: -1 }

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to get records in my query and i am using waterfall method but it says error with the following query ,can anyone suggest help.Thanks.

My js,

```
    exports.gettopics = (err, res) => {
  async.waterfall([
    (callback) => {
      var item = {
        'status': '1',
        'type': 'topics'
      };
       Topics.find(item,{ sort: { 'created_at' : -1 } }, (err, sols)=>{
        callback(err, sols); //If err is true, async.waterfall will cut to it's callback
      });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using sort the wrong way. Try this:

```
Topics.find(item).sort({ 'created_at' : -1 }).toArray((err, sols)=>{
        callback(err, sols);
      });
```

Check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#combine-cursor-methods) for more details.

Comment: Hi Andresk,i am getting the error,Error: sort() only takes 1 Argument

Comment: Humm it seems mongoose will not accept the callback inside the sort. I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
   Topics.find(item, null, { sort: { 'created_at' : -1 } }, (err, sols)=>{
    callback(err, sols); //If err is true, async.waterfall will cut to it's callback
  });
```